# How do I use piechartmp to make pie charts with Metapost?

Tags: diagrams, metapost

This is my MetaPost input file:

```
prologues := 3 ;
outputformat := "%j-%c.eps" ;

input piechartmp;

beginfig(1);
  SetupColors((0.7, 0.7), this, this) ;
  SetupPercent(this, "%") ;

  Segment(64, "acc") ; 
  Segment(24, "bak") ;
  Segment(12, "ext") ;

  SegmentState(3, this, 0.3) ;

  PieChart(2cm, 0.15, 60, 0,0) ;

  Label.auto(0) (name) (outwards, 0) ;
  Label(1)(percent) (inwards, 0) withcolor (1, 1, 0) ;
  Label(2)(percent) (inwards, 0) withcolor (1, 1, 0) ;
  Label(3)(percent) (inwards, 0) withcolor (1, 1, 0) ;

  pickup pencircle scaled 2pt;
endfig;

end.
```

This is my makefile:

```
NAME=piechart
PDFVIEWER=acroread

all :
    mptopdf ${NAME}.mp
    mv -f ${NAME}.1 ${NAME}.eps
    mv -f ${NAME}-1.pdf ${NAME}.pdf
    ${PDFVIEWER} ${NAME}.pdf &
```

This is the output

[image]

I want to change 2 things:

1) I want the pie "ext" to be drawn lower than the rest.
   How do you do that?

2) I don't want "64%" for internal label of acc, I want 
   the string `64% - 269 GiB`. How to do that?

Comment: I don't think you can "lower" slices - but the [comprehensive manual](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/piechartmp/piechartmp.pdf) will tell you for sure.  Changing the labels is in section 3.4

Comment: your `outputformat` line is doing nothing by the way - you can delete it.  If you wanted to produce an `.eps` file directly use `outputtemplate` which has superseded the old command.  But with your `makefile` you don't need it.

Comment: Random comment: 3d pie charts are generally considered less useful than the 2d version because the 3d perspective distorts the relative sizes of the slices.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

Personally I would set such a simple data set as a plain table rather than a pie chart, but assuming we do want to do this as a pie chart, I recommend reading the [manual available on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/piechartmp) carefully.

Here's a slightly simpler way to achieve what I think you might want:

```
prologues := 3 ;
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.eps";

input piechartmp;

beginfig(1);
label(btex \bf Your Title Here etex, (0,2cm));

  SetupColors((0.7, 0.7), this, this) ;
  SetupText(1,"","")
  SetupPercent(this, "\%");
  SetupValue(this, "\thinspace GiB");

  Segment(269, "acc") ;   
  Segment(100, "bak") ;
  Segment( 50, "ext") ;

  SegmentState(3, this, 0.4) ;

  PieChart(2.5cm, 0.15, 60, 290,0) ;

  Label.auto(0)(name) (inwards, 0) withcolor red+green;
  Label.auto(0)(percent,"${}\simeq{}$", value) (outwards,0);

endfig;
end.
```

This produces:

[image]

### Notes

- to make a title, just use a normal MP `label` command.  But use it **before** doing the rest of the pie chart.  For reference, the centre of the pie is at point `(0,0)`.
- give the real values in the `Segment` commands -- it will work out the percentages automatically
- use `SetupText(1,"","")` to typeset the labels with TeX
- use `SetupValue` to add a suffix to the data values
- use `SetupPercent` to add a suffix to the calculated percentage value
- combine `percent` and `value` as shown to make the label you want
- put long labels outside the pie slices and short ones inside
- use the fourth parameter to `Piechart` to rotate the whole chart -- this has the side effect of making the separated slice come to the front and hence to  appear lower
- read [manual available on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/piechartmp)